# Php Script not able to upload image on server

Tags: php, iphone, ios, image

I have a requirement to upload image on server in 2 size, normal and small size.

So i am sending http request to php file, i am successfully able to upload Image on server in normal form,

But when i am trying to resize and then uploading it on server, it is not uploading..

So here is my php script

```
<php

define ("MAX_SIZE","400");

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
   $image =$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
   $uploadedfile = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

if ($image) 
{

    $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

    $extension = getExtension($filename);
    $extension = strtolower($extension);

            if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
    {
        $errors=1;
    }
    else
    {
                    $size=filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
                    if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
                    {
                       $errors=1;
                    }
                    if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" )
                    {
                           $uploadedfile = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
                           $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
                    }


                    list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);

                    $newwidth = 70;                  
                    $newheight = 70;

                    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);

                    imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);



                    $file_name = substr ( md5(uniqid(rand(),1)), 5, 15); 


                    $iconuploaddir = "/home/announce/public_html/TravelApp/images/$output/icons/";

                    $file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
                    $newname = $file_name . $file;

                    $uploadIconfile = $iconuploaddir . $newname;


                    if (move_uploaded_file($temp, $uploadIconfile)) {
                           $imagepath =  $baseuploaddir;// Give the path where the image saves. or print some messages
                    }

                    imagedestroy($src);
                    imagedestroy($tmp);                      
           }
        }
 }
?>
```

i guess move_uploaded_file($temp, $uploadIconfile)) is the main cause of problem

please help me.

Comment: why someone wold like to read lots of partly commented code?

Comment: @k102 because he is asking for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot be using `move_uploaded_file` for the thumbnail because the thumbnail file was not uploaded

You can use this function to create the thumbnail after calling `move_uploaded_file` for the file that was uploaded

```
function make_thumb($src,$dest,$desired_width)
{

  /* read the source image */
  $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
  $width = imagesx($source_image);
  $height = imagesy($source_image);

  /* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
  $desired_height = floor($height*($desired_width/$width));

  /* create a new, "virtual" image */
  $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width,$desired_height);

  /* copy source image at a resized size */
  imagecopyresized($virtual_image,$source_image,0,0,0,0,$desired_width,$desired_height,$width,$height);

  /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */
  imagejpeg($virtual_image,$dest);
}
```

For the `$src` param pass `$imagepath` and for `$dest`, put the destination you want the thumbmail image to be saved.

Comment: when i tried to use this function, 

PHP Warning:  imagejpeg() [<a href='function.imagejpeg'>function.imagejpeg</a>]: Unable to open '/home/announce/public_html/TravelApp/images/TajMahal/icons/' for writing: Is a directory in /home/announce/public_html/TravelApp/php/test-upload.php..

Whta the error??

Comment: change the write permission of the directory to 777 or something that can enable you to write to it

Comment: Hey i am able to solve it out, i googled it found out that path to $dest needs to be correct.So after doing it it was successfully uploaded.Thanks a lot @yankitwizzy